Earlier and Latest date of two columns
I am analyzing some data that has two DateTime columns indicating the date of starting production of different products for a facility. So the data looks like this:
FacilityID, DateStart Product1, DateStart Product2
111, 2022-02-01, 2022-01-15
200, 2019-01-01, 2019-03-01

My result needs to be the earliest of the two dates. The result would show this:
FacilityID, Start Date
111, 2022-01-15
200, 2019-01-01

I may be wrong; but I have not found an out-of-the-box function that can check two dates and give me the earliest (or latest) of the two dates.
Any ideas how to do this?

I came up with this and it works great:
If(DateDiff('day',[DateStart Product1],[DateStart Product2])<=0,[DateStart Product2],[DateStart Product1])

If that gives me a negative number or zero then I know my Product2 is the earliest. Positive and my Product 1 is the earliest. Hope that helps!

Try it using case statement
select 
FacilityId,
CASE
    WHEN Date1 < Date2 THEN Date1
    ELSE Date2
END AS Start_Date
from your_table;


I am not sure a SQL statement will work in Spotfire, but the spirit of the answer is correct. CASE WHEN... END will give you a calculated column with the start date.

Min([DateStart Product1],[DateStart Product2])

